# Detect specific exception parsing an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to detect specific exceptions in an xml file, such as

1. "The 'childone' start tag on line 1 position 45 does not match the end tag of 'node'. Line 1, position 82."
2. "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 45."

Say my xml string is

```
<root><node some=\"fggfg\"><childone>name is &&</childone><childtwo>name9</childtwo></node>\n</root>
```

where a special char is present which is & and LoadXml method throws exception no. 2 and for missing node it throws exception no. 1.

```
if (!isXmlParse(inputXml, out exceptionMsg))
{
   bool done = XmlEscaper (inputXml, out escapeXml);
}
```

Where my expectation is isXmlParse method returns false only when xml value contains special char(like example xml above) and return true even for missing node or any other error and return the exception message to out param. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Of what types are the Exceptions? When they are different, you can easily handle them differently.

Comment: @fast Well, LoadXml method only throws XmlException(which caught all possible exceptions in an xml). But if we notice to the message it defers depend on different mistakes in xml. For example, if a node is missing XmlException gives message like 1 in question and if xml values contains special char such as & > " ' < then XmlException gives message like 2. I need to return false by my isXmlParse method only and only if xml values contains some special char, it means exception message 2 in the question and for other any exception whether a a node is missing or anything it it must return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a warning: I highly encourage you to have the XML be fixed at the place where it is generated. Do not use string concatenation to generate the XML. Tell to whoever creates the XML that he's doing something really wrong. Using `XmlDocument` or other dedicated XML handling classes will automatically convert the `&` into `&amp;` and result in valid XML.

Besides that, you can implemented exactly as decribed by you in text form.

- Catch the exception
- Check the error message
- Based on the result, return true or false

  ```
  private static bool isXmlParse(string inputXml, out string exceptionMsg)
  {
      // TODO: Career warning - implementing workarounds instead of real fixes may harm your career.
      try
      {
          var d = new XmlDocument();
          d.LoadXml(inputXml);
          exceptionMsg = null;
      }
      catch (XmlException ex)
      {
          exceptionMsg = ex.Message;
          if (ex.Message.StartsWith("An error occurred while parsing EntityName"))
              return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

Warning number 2: the method XmlEscaper() will not be easy to implement You can't simply replace `&` by `&amp;` unless you are sure that all occurences of `&` are invalid. If the XML looks like

```
...<childdone>name is &amp;&</childdone>...
```

you must only replace the second `&` character. I'll definitely leave this part up to you.

Comment: well, unfortunately I do not have any access to xml source other than I can download it even don't know who creates it. I tried the same approach u provided  but I'm not mush happy with comparing strings. If any way to create user define exception or something else. And about XmlEscaper() it does work real fast with 56000 lines of xml file and all special char of values are replaced.

Comment: In that case it would have been nice to see that you have already tried this solution. On StackOverflow, please post the code which does not work for you. I have no doubt that replacing characters is fast. It's a quite stupid operation.

Comment: @Rahul if the XMLEscaper works that well than just run it on any XML file.. if exceptions remain when parsing afterwards, it will be errors regarding the structure of the document.

Comment: @ThomasW. You perhaps right. Well true, is isn't very fast. but XmlEscaper() works good. I'll post the code. If possible, then please help to improve the code and I guess it can be. Because, I do not access to source this is only way to fix the xml.